# select has Extra top padding from div

Tags: html, css

I want a dropdown with custom arrow.
I have made a div wrapper with arrow image background around my select.

The problem is that the select has 3-4 pixels top padding from  the div. And I can't find the reason.

```
<style>

    .styleSelect select {
        font-weight:bold;
        -moz-appearance:none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border:none;
        width: 140px;
    }

    .styleSelect select::-ms-expand {
        display: none;
    }

    .styleSelect {
        width: 120px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: url("/Images/dropdown_arrow.gif") no-repeat right #fff;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 3px;
        border-radius: 8px;
    }

</style>
```

Here is my html:

```
<form>
    <div class="styleSelect">     
        <select></select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: borders extend the element. Try removing the vorder: 1px solid #000; or add box-sizing: border-box

Comment: Try to set a `line-height` to the height of the navbar and the `height` of the select to the height of the navbar

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @DarkAshelin done, posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:
For this example I use a navbar height of 50px but for the 50 you can use your own navbar or parent object height.

```
.styleSelect select{
  line-height:50px;
  height:50px;
  /*and ofcourse your other code*/
}
```

This should center the object vertical.
You can also try `vertical-align:middle;`

Answer (score 0):

Hey I also found that if I add `font-size: 0 px`  to the div - that also worked